# maven deploy:file too many folders get created while uploading the artifact in nexus

Tags: shell, unix, maven-3, sonatype, maven-deploy-plugin

I am using maven:deploy deploy-file to upload the artifacts from my local to remote nexus using shell script, every thing is working as expected. The problem is suppose there is a artifact

```
    a/b/1.2.3/ab-1.2.3.jar
```

Then in nexus the folder structure created is

```
     a/b/1/2/3/ab-1.2.3/1.2.3/ab-1.2.3-1.2.3.jar
```

which is not right, I even tried to escape the .(period with /. and also tried \.) but at runtime it is considering it as another folder and the deployment get failed, since that location is not available. Any help would be great. Below is the output message from the build I am running to push the jar

```
 Uploading: https://myrepo/nexus/repository/release-repo/a/b/1/2/3/ab-1.2.3.jar
```

Below is the command i am using

```
   mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=${group_id:1} -DartifactId=${name_and_version} -Dversion=${artifact_version} -DgeneratePom=false -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=releases -Durl=https://myrepo/nexus/repository/release-repo -Dfile=${only_path}/${name_and_version}.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=.keystore -s settings.xml -DpomFile=${only_path}/${name_and_version}.pom
```

Also while debugging this is the output I am getting

```
   [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) artifactId = abc-1.2.3 
[DEBUG]   (f) file = C:\dev\resources\a\b\1.2.3\abc-1.2.3.jar
[DEBUG]   (f) generatePom = false
[DEBUG]   (f) groupId = a.b.1.2.3
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///c:/dev/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) offline = false
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = jar
[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = C:\dev\resources\a\b\1.2.3\abc-1.2.3..pom
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:1 @
[DEBUG]   (f) repositoryId = releases
[DEBUG]   (f) repositoryLayout = default
[DEBUG]   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) uniqueVersion = true
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false
[DEBUG]   (f) url = https://myewpo/nexus/repository/release
[DEBUG]   (f) version = 1.2.3
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

Comment: Why are putting `1.2.3` ? Artifacts are defined by groupId, artifactId and version? Please add the command you have tried ...?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am not putting that 1.2.3 these are the jar files I have downloaded and their structure(I mean folder sturucture) is like that. so i am trying to push those jars in our private repository

Comment: Why is there version in the artifact name?

Comment: @khmarbaise that's the way artifact is provided to us. Verified the debug logs, which I have mentioned here. It's right in a sense all the information is printed here.

Comment: The only thing I can see is that the pom file contains a supplemental `.` ... `C:\dev\resources\a\b\1.2.3\abc-1.2.3..pom` furthermore the groupId given as `a.b.1.2.3` is translated to a directory structure which is separated at each `.` as the java package names...then the artifactId is taken `ab-1.2.3` and continued with the version `a/b/1/2/3/ab-1.2.3/1.2.3/` and finally adding the artifactId including the version number `a/b/1/2/3/ab-1.2.3/1.2.3/ab-1.2.3-1.2.3.jar` ...so I don't see any issue here ..apart from that strange groupId/artifactId given...

Comment: Well, you specified groupID of "a.b.1.2.3", so that will give you exactly the directory structure you're seeing.   But in any case, you don't need to supply the coordinates for since you have a pom file, the coordinates will be taken from the pom file.